# How to write Scala console output to a XML file?

Tags: json, xml, scala, console

I'm trying to convert json to xml, I am getting full output in console if the json file is small but I am trying to pass large  json file n I'm not getting the entire output in the console

Comment: Can you provide a *minimum* example of your code that write to a console? And why you write to the console (not to a file)?

Comment: I'm not aware of how to write it to a file